# Problema al introducir y leer datos en clase JavaScript

Tags: javascript, poo

En este fragmento de programación orientado a objetos debo crear una única clase con un indicador "edificio" y las propiedades “nombre”, “descripción”, “dirección”, “data inauguración”, “arquitecto” y “coste”. Debe poseer métodos para consultar y modificar las propiedades mencionadas, un método constructor de la clase (que intuyo que será la creación de la función de la clase) y, posteriormente, crear otro método que muestre en una ventana modal todas las propiedades. Finalmente debo crear una instancia de la clase anterior y llamar al método que muestra las propiedades.

Posteriormente he añadido un documento HTML5 con el siguiente fragmento para llamar al programa javascript mediante un botón.

Este es el código que he usado:

```js
function edificio() {
  this.nombre = nombre;
  this.descripcion = descripcion;
  this.direccion = direccion;
  this.inauguracion = inauguracion;
  this.arquitecto = arquitecto;
  this.coste = 0;
}
edificio.prototype.consultarnombre() {
  return nombre;
}
edificio.prototype.nombrar(nombre) {
  this.nombre = nombre;
}
edificio.prototype.consultardescripcion() {
  return descripcion;
}
edificio.prototype.describir(descripcion) {
  this.descripcion = descripcion;
}
edificio.prototype.consultardireccion() {
  return direccion;
}
edificio.prototype.direccion(direccion) {
  this.direccion = direccion;
}
edificio.prototype.consultarinauguracion() {
  return inauguracion;
}
edificio.prototype.inaugurar(inauguracion) {
  this.inauguracion = inauguracion;
}
edificio.prototype.consultararquitecto() {
  return arquitecto;
}
edificio.prototype.arquitecto(arquitecto) {
  this.arquitecto = arquitecto;
}
edificio.prototype.consultarcoste() {
  return coste;
}
edificio.prototype.precio(coste) {
  this.coste = coste;
}

edificio.prototype.muestra() {
    alert(nombre + ". " + descripcion + ". " + direccion + ". Inaugurado el 
      "+inauguracion+".Creado por "+arquitecto+".Vale "+coste);
    }

    var miedificio = new edificio();
    miedificio.nombrar("Salmon")
    miedificio.muestra();
```

```html
<p>POO
  <form name="miform">
    <input type="button" name="boton" value="Pulsa para empezar" onClick="javaScript: edificio()">
  </form>
</p>
```

El problema es que ni siquiera se ejecuta el llamamiento que hago a la ventana modal. No sale ni NaN, ya que por el momento no he introducido ningún dato. ¿Como lo puedo solucionar?

Tampoco se como podría modificar las propiedades con los métodos, es decir, introducir los datos.

Comment: Estas llamando directamente al objeto edificio, cuando quizás necesitas llamar a algún método de ese objeto

Comment: He probado en poner: onClick="javascript:muestra()" y tampoco aparece nada @EugeniBejan

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tienes algunos errores, debo recalcar que algunos son fundamentales. En tu html llamas a la función `edificio()`, si ves lo que tienes en tu archivo js te darás cuenta que no hace nada excepto asignar valores a tus propiedades, que por cierto deberías **inicializarlas** con valores por defecto ya que el constructor no recibe ningún parámetro.

Por tanto deberias crear en tu html una función que cree una instancia de edificio, le establezca las propiedades y ya que quieres que muestre el cartel, llame entonces a la función muestra. Y por último la manera de asignarle las funciones al prototype no era la correcta en tu código deberia ser `objeto.prototype.function_name = function(){}`

```js
function edificio(){
  this.nombre='';
  this.descripcion='';
  this.direccion='';
  this.inauguracion=null;
  this.arquitecto='';
  this.coste=0;
}

edificio.prototype.consultarnombre = function(){
  return nombre;
}
edificio.prototype.nombrar = function(nombre){
  this.nombre=nombre;
}
edificio.prototype.consultardescripcion = function(){
  return descripcion;
}
edificio.prototype.describir = function(descripcion){
  this.descripcion=descripcion;
}
edificio.prototype.consultardireccion = function(){
  return this.direccion;
}
edificio.prototype.direccion = function(direccion){
  this.direccion=direccion;
}
edificio.prototype.consultarinauguracion = function(){
  return this.inauguracion;
}
edificio.prototype.inaugurar = function(inauguracion){
  this.inauguracion=inauguracion;
}
edificio.prototype.consultararquitecto = function(){
  return this.arquitecto;
}
edificio.prototype.arquitecto = function(arquitecto){
  this.arquitecto=arquitecto;
}
edificio.prototype.consultarcoste = function(){
  return this.coste;
}
edificio.prototype.precio = function(coste){
  this.coste=coste;
}

edificio.prototype.muestra = function(){
  alert(this.nombre+". "+this.descripcion+". "+
      this.direccion+". Inaugurado el "+this.direccion+
      ". Inaugurado el "+this.inauguracion+". Creado por "+
      this.arquitecto+". Vale "+this.coste);
}
  
var mi_edificio = function(){
   var ed = new edificio();
   ed.nombrar("Principal");
   ed.precio(2200);
   ed.muestra();
}
```

```html
<p>POO
  <form name="miform">
   <input type="button" name="boton" value="Pulsa para empezar" 
   onClick="javaScript: mi_edificio();" >
  </form>
  </p>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Dariel!!!!

Comment: No hay de que. Salu2s

Comment: @DarielRamosDíazdeVillegas, te falto corregir todos los métodos `edificio.prototype.consultar****`, ya que debería hacer `return this.***`, de lo contrario dará error si las variables globales no existe o devolverá cualquier otro valor del esperado.